# Is it possible to enable PDF Crawling in Foundation 2010 Search?

Tags: 2010, development, search, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to enable PDF crawling for Foundation Search V4, but have only been able to find resources for PDF crawling for the complete versions of 2010 - Some of the instructions and procedures vary between these versions, so I suspect the problem is regarding these differences.

Has anyone had any success getting PDF Search Crawling spun up on foundation 2010, and if so, how did you go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can enable it on Foundation 2010 using PowerShell

```
    function AddExtention([string] $extension){ 

    if ($extension -eq $null) { 
        Write-host "No extention Found" 
    } 
    else{ 
        Write-host "Activating extension $extension" 

        $gadmin = new-object -comobject "SPSearch4.GatherMgr.1" -strict 

        Foreach ($application in $gadmin.GatherApplications) 
        { 
            write-host "application name is $application.name" 
            Foreach ($project in $application.GatherProjects) 
            { 
                write-host $project.Extensions 
                $project.Gather.Extensions.Add($extension) 
            } 

        } 
    } 
} 

function AddPdfRegKey(){ 

    $pdfKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Search\Setup\ContentIndexCommon\Filters\Extension\.pdf" 

    $pdfguid = "{E8978DA6-047F-4E3D-9C78-CDBE46041603}" 

    if (Test-Path $pdfKey) {   
        write-host "Pdf registry key already exists"  

        $key = Get-Item $pdfKey 
        $values = Get-ItemProperty $key.PSPath 
        foreach ($value in $key.Property) { $value + "=" + $values.$value } 
    } 
    else {   
        Write-host "creating key $pdfKey" 

        #create key 
        New-Item -Path $pdfKey 

        #Set default value to good guid 
        $defaultKeyName = "(default)" 
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $pdfKey -Name $defaultKeyName -Value $pdfguid 
    } 


} 

AddExtention "pdf" 
AddPdfRegKey 

& net stop SPSearch4 
& net start SPSearch4 

Write-host "running a fullcrawlstart..." 
&stsadm -o spsearch -action fullcrawlstart
```

taken from [Blog](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Activate-pdf-search-in-cc8bc9bc)

I never personally tried it but I am sure it will effect your server performance as if you have hundred and hundred of sites :)

hope it helped !